# To show two formal power series equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, formal-power-series, algebraic-combinatorics

I am wondering whether the following two formal power series are equal:
$A(x)=\Pi_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-x^{2k-1}}$, $B(x)=\Pi_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+x^k)$.

Comment: A and B are not series.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: They are both series: $A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n|\text{parts all odd})x^n$ and $B(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n|\text{parts distinct})x^n$. Here $p(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1+x^k)}&=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(1+x^k)(1-x^k)}{1-x^k}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1-x^{2k}}{1-x^k}\color{blue}{=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1-x^{2k-1}}}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comment, it's very clear!

Comment: @luw: You're welcome.

Comment: Why is the last equality true? Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: @callculus: The numerator $1-x^{2k}, 1\leq k\leq \infty$ contains all even natural exponents, the denominator even and odd. Cancellation leaves the odd terms in the denominator.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Very quick and clear respond. I´ve thought about a long time and now it is so obvious. Nochmals vielen Dank.

Comment: @callculus: You're welcome and thanks for the credit. :-)